# Insert Calculated Row into Temp Table with Variable Number of Rows and Columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns only locations that have made a purchase within the time frame that the user specifies, so the number of rows is variable. Then, the query finds all the types of spending those locations have done, and pivots it to create a dynamic number of columns.

So what I am left with is a table that has all the locations with spending and a sum of the spending in the categories in which they spent.

What I would like to do now is to insert a new row at the top that is an average across all locations in the table for each of the columns, but I'm not sure how to do that across a variable number of rows and columns.

Do any of you know how to do this? I have not posted any code because it's about 90 lines, but if that would help, I can.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is my code. I removed as much extraneous code as possible (and anonymized table names) so that you can see succinctly what I have so far.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @RunForText varchar(max), 
    @Periods varchar(max)

Set @RunForText = 
(
SELECT  Distinct Stuff((Select ',' + c.Location
From Table..Table1 c  For Xml Path ('')), 1, 1, ''))  --GET UNIQUE LOCATIONS

Set @Periods = '201703' --SET TIME PERIOD FOR REPORT

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(vw.Description) --GET UNIQUE CATEGORIES OF SPEND AS COLUMNS
                FROM Table..Table vw
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')


set @query = 'SELECT p.Number, ' + @cols + ' 
        into ##tmp
        from 
        (
          SELECT 
            vw.Number,
            vw.Name,
            [Total] = vw.Total,
            Description

        FROM Table..Table vw

            ) p
            pivot 
            (
                SUM(p.Total)
                for p.Description in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute sp_executesql @query;

SELECT * FROM ##tmp
```

Currently, the Output looks like this:

```
 NUMBER | Category1 | Category2 | Category3
 01       100.00      125.00      15.00
 02       1.41        23.42       14.89
```

I would like to insert a row so that the table looks like this:

```
 NUMBER | Category1 | Category2 | Category3
 Average  50.70       74.21       14.94
 01       100.00      125.00      15.00
 02       1.40        23.42       14.88
```

Comment: better to paste your code.. especially which part you get stucked

Comment: Without the code at the absolute minimum this isn't even a question.

Comment: Working on it..

Comment: In addition to the code, please also include some sample data and the desired output.  The desired output by itself can answer a number of questions.

Comment: Let me know if that helps--thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a similar method to the way you are creating the pivot query, but surround the column names with a call to `Avg`.  Based on the code you posted, it would look like:

```
declare @avgcols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @avgcols = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct ',avg(' + QUOTENAME(vw.Description) + ')'
    FROM Table..Table vw
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

set @query = 
    'INSERT into ##tmp (Number,' + @cols + ')
    into ##tmp
    Select ''Average'',' + @avgcols + ' FROM ##tmp'

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Answer (score 0):

The big road block for your current approach is the pivot operator.  It only supports one aggregation function at a time ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) - Microsoft Docs).  That means you cannot combine sums, mins, maxs and averages.

There is a reason for this.  Each column has a purpose.  But in your example, `Col1` has two jobs.  Sometimes it contains a sum, sometimes an average.  That's an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), that I like to avoid.  You cannot build on top of columns, that have inconsistent contents.

Of course in your case you are just trying to add a total/sub total row.  Not exactly a crime!  Still where possible this kind of operation is best performed in the [presentation layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_layer).  One good reason, often it is much easier!

My example uses conditional aggregation (mixing the [group by clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) with a number of [case expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql)), instead of the pivot.  But the result is the same.

At a high level, the basic approach is:

1. Get your data.
2. Sum it.
3. Append averages.
4. Sort as required.

Query

```
/* Returns sample data with average sub total row.
 */
WITH SampleData AS
(
    -- Conditional aggregation used instead of Pivot.       
    SELECT
        Nu,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Cat = 'C1' THEN Tot ELSE 0 END)   AS C1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Cat = 'C2' THEN Tot ELSE 0 END)   AS C2,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Cat = 'C3' THEN Tot ELSE 0 END)   AS C3       
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
            (1, 'C1', 100.00),
            (2, 'C1', 1.41),
            (1, 'C2', 125.00),
            (2, 'C2', 23.42),
            (1, 'C3', 15.00),
            (2, 'C3', 14.89)
        ) AS c(Nu, Cat, Tot)
    GROUP BY 
        nu
)
    -- Returns detail rows.
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        SampleData

UNION ALL

    -- Returns average row.
    SELECT
        '0'     AS Nu,
        AVG(C1) AS C1,
        AVG(C2) AS C2,
        AVG(C3) AS C3
    FROM
        SampleData
    ORDER BY
        Nu
;
```

Returns

```
Nu  C1      C2      C3
0   50.71   74.21   14.95
1   100.00  125.00  15.00
2   1.41    23.42   14.89
```

You could also achieve the same results with a temp table and a couple of insert statements.

As you can see.  This is one ugly query,  There is a lot going on.  Converting this into [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql) won't be fun.  This is why I would recommend you don't use it.